# Update table with conditions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I just came across a scenario i.e there is table BATCH with 10 records with column sl_no and batch_typ like below.

[image: Table Batch]

Here I want to update the Batch_typ where BLUE it should be green and vice versa with SQL query.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may update using a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE BATCH
SET BATCH_TYP = CASE WHEN BATCH_TYP = 'GREEN' THEN 'BLUE' ELSE 'GREEN' END
WHERE BATCH_TYP IN ('GREEN', 'BLUE');
```

Comment: Hi Tim , i have already try this approach but it is not working the output will be like first 1-5 where it should be Green are coming null and 6-10 will be Blue .So with case it is not possible. Please let me know if any other approach you have

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and provide sample input and output which helps to explain what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below update statement,

```
update BATCH set batch_typ =
case when batch_typ = 'BLUE' then 'GREEN'
     when batch_typ = 'GREEN' then 'BLUE' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update with Case for this kind of scenarios

`````````````````
UPDATE BATCH set batch_typ =
case when batch_typ = 'BLUE' then 'GREEN'
     when batch_typ = 'GREEN' then 'BLUE' end;

````````````````
`````````````````